# Manga where main character goes missing for 14 years in a martial arts world then comes back to modern day

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is stuck in cave-like setting for a while and has to learn some art, then spends like 140 years in a different world (murim type). When he returns, he saves his sister and finds out he's been gone for like 14 years, as well as that there were others like him.

Comment: If [Kadath's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/279021/122024) below is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. If you click on the correct icon, it should turn green, and you will earn +2 reputation. If that doesn't happen, then it means the answer hasn't been marked as accepted yet.

Answer (score 12):

This should be [Leveling Beyond the Max](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/z3s4b0y/leveling-beyond-the-max).
The main character, Cha Shinhyeon, was a passenger in his parents' car together with them and his sister Cha Eunseol, and suddendly found himself in a cave with a *status board* that stated **See it to the end**.

He was also given a book called **Heavenly Martial Origin Cultivation Art**. He thinks that he must master it in order to go back home, but even after ten years spent mastering it and finally succeeding in doing so, after getting out of the cave he finds himself in a Murim world. He his attacked by a person that wants to eat his flesh and, after killing him to survive, he gains a level. Then he thinks that in order to get back he must reach the max level and, after a total of 140 years spent in Murim he has become the *Supreme Sword Emperor*.
Since he's so strong he has become bored and wants to end his life but, lo and behold, a status message pops up saying that he has reached the highest level. He finally gets sent back to Earth.

He believes that he has nothing left to live for since so much time has passed and his family must all be dead at this point in time, and vows to kill whoever was that sent him in Murim.

Obviously, on Earth not that long has passed. Gates have appeared and monsters have started pouring out. His sister has now become a team leader for a hunter squad. She is in a dungeon where her squad has been annihilated due to the incompetence of some big shot's son. He tries to kill her to cover his trying to flee and our hero, Cha Shinhyeon, is at that moment sent to the dungeon where this was happening and kils him.

This are just the first two chapters in the manhwa. There is way more stuff happening after that. I personally enjoyed it quite a bit.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jahdai - if this answer is correct please mark is as accepted by clicking on the check mark below the voting buttons